# Disabling authentication popup for info-path form page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created a custom login page, after login it redirects to a info-path form page. But again in info-path page it asks for SharePoint authentication.

Is there any way that the authentication popup can be stopped from coming after the person logins.

Comment: Does 'custom login page' mean Form-based authentication? What is your SP version?

Comment: Are you sure the domain name used in the URL of both the login page and the InfoPath page are the same? Maybe an AAM problem?

Comment: yes domain is same butthe form based authentication is for anonymous user. So, for anonymous user it again asks for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fiddler to diagnose if anything else is being 'touched' by the request that is causing the authentication request.